# Conditional field calculator expression

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, syntax

I need to calculate the PIPEID field to equal the G_KEY_COMP field if PIPEID is null or PIPEID and G_KEY_COMP do not match.  I think the first condition of the PIPEID being null is covered by the second condition of the fields not matching?  I'm a novice on this topic and can't get the syntax I have to work. Here's what I've piecemealed together:

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def update(PIPEID,G_KEY_COMP):
 if PIPEID != G_KEY_COMP
  return G_KEY_COMP
else:
 return PIPEID
```

PIPEID = update(!PIPEID!, !G_KEY_COMP!)

I'm posting a screenshot of the field calculator window since I'm not able to get the indentation right in the codeblock.

[image]

Comment: if and else need to be indented the same amount, inside the function

Comment: also there is a missing : at the end of the if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code needs to be:

```
def update(PIPEID,G_KEY_COMP):
  if PIPEID is None:
    # PIPEID is NULL
    return G_KEY_COMP
  if PIPEID != G_KEY_COMP:
    # PIPEID has a different value to G_KEY_COMP
    return G_KEY_COMP
  else:
    return PIPEID
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this snippet and it gives a syntax error 000989 on line 5.  Not sure why as it looks good to me.  Also, thank you for including comments :)

Comment: again, : is missing after the second if

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic inline if is working in Field Calculator expression

```
res=(on_false, on_true)[condition]

arcpy.CalculateField_management("fc" , "field" ,"(!PIPEID!, !G_KEY_COMP!)[!PIPEID! != !G_KEY_COMP!]" , "PYTHON_9.3")
```